# Explode using 2 delimiter for a single line

Tags: php, mysql, import

i need to upload a .txt file in database. 
my .txt file is exactly looks like

```
Name|Code|Email|Designation|Number|Salary|Age\t
syed|101|syed@gmail.com|trainee|7222877798|6000|21\t
hari|102|hari@gmail.com|trainee|9554512582|6000|23\t
```

i have need to separate it with `|` and then `\t`.

while getting array, the first one achieved as what i expect. but i cant able make `\t` explode.. can any one help me on this forum??
my routine is described below

```
   if ($_POST['frmSubmit']) {
            $file = $_FILES['frmUpload']['tmp_name'];           //  Get Temporary filename
                $handle = fopen($file,"r");                         //  Open the file and read
                while($strBookData = fgets($handle, 4096)) {        //  To get Array from .txt
                    $strDatas[] = $strBookData;
                    $strTableColumn = count($strBookData);  

                }
                $strDatas = explode("|",implode($strDatas));

                printArray($strDatas); exit;

                if ($strDatas) {
                    $strInsertRecords = 0;
                    $strDuplicationRecords = 0;
                    if ($strTableColumn == 7) {
                        for($k=1; $k<count($strDatas); $k++) { //$k=1 is initialized because $k[0] is a header field array.
                            $strStatus  =   doCheckDuplication($strDatas[$k]['2']);                 
                            if ($strStatus == 0) {
                                // Insert Code  
                                $strData = $strDatas[$k];
                                doInsertEmployeeDetails($strData['0'], $strData['1'], $strDatas[$k]['2'], $strData['3'], $strData['4'], $strData['5'], $strData['6']);
                                $strInsertRecords++;            // To Get Inserted Records Count.
                            } else {
                                $strDuplicationRecords++;       // To Get Duplication Records Count.
                            }
                        }
                }
    }
```

Comment: Your file has literally has a ``\`` and `t` characters in it? Because `\t` in php double-quoted strings is interpreted as a tab character (one char), not two chars. You'd have to do `explode("\\t", ...)` instead.

Comment: Use `fgetcsv` with custom delimeters?

Comment: Slightly offtopic: why use `\t` at the end of each line? You could also explode on line-break (`\n`).

Comment: @FDL is correct, fgetcsv with a | delimiter is ideal.  While at it, save yourself some headache and also turn on: ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

Comment: ya its really good to do with fgetcsv as('',,'|') but i should not use fgetcsv for this task..thanx brother..  @FDL :)

Comment: I need some nails driven, can you please do it with a screwdriver?

Comment: fgetcsv won't work with the lines split on \t instead of \n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this will split the text you provided.

```
    $text = 'Name|Code|Email|Designation|Number|Salary|Age\t
    syed|101|syed@gmail.com|trainee|7222877798|6000|21\t
    hari|102|hari@gmail.com|trainee|9554512582|6000|23\t';

    //remove line endings
    $text = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "", $text);

    $rows = explode('\t', $text);
    $data = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row){
            //don't include empty lines
        if(!empty( $row )){
            $data[] = explode('|', $row);
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    var_export( $data );
```

Outputs:

```
array (
            0 =>
            array (
                    0 => 'Name',
                    1 => 'Code',
                    2 => 'Email',
                    3 => 'Designation',
                    4 => 'Number',
                    5 => 'Salary',
                    6 => 'Age',
            ),
            1 =>
            array (
                    0 => 'syed',
                    1 => '101',
                    2 => 'syed@gmail.com',
                    3 => 'trainee',
                    4 => '7222877798',
                    5 => '6000',
                    6 => '21',
            ),
            2 =>
            array (
                    0 => 'hari',
                    1 => '102',
                    2 => 'hari@gmail.com',
                    3 => 'trainee',
                    4 => '9554512582',
                    5 => '6000',
                    6 => '23',
            ),
    );
```

However that said, there is a lot going on in your example, as for reading the file in.  If it's not to large the best bet would be to use `file_get_contents()` that will read the whole file in one go.  Otherwise in this part

```
   $handle = fopen($file,"r");                         //  Open the file and read
   while($strBookData = fgets($handle, 4096)) {        //  To get Array from
        $strDatas[] = $strBookData;
        $strTableColumn = count($strBookData);  
   }
```

You would be better off just concatenating the text.

```
   $strDatas = '';
   $handle = fopen($file,"r");                         //  Open the file and read
   while($strBookData = fgets($handle, 4096)) {        //  To get Array from
        $strDatas .= $strBookData; 
   }
```

And then splitting like I did above.

Comment: Sure thing, was pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should first explode using '\t' as delimiter to get the substrings separated by \t (Name|Code|Email|Designation|Number|Salary|Age)
and then explode each substring using '|' as delimiter.
I wish that can help you

Comment: yes i know,, but i have some problem regards with it. please can u give some description?? :)